# Prove that optimal Solution exist without solving.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osa3G.jpg

Without solving the problem, show that it has an optimal solution.

Comment: The domain is compact, the function is continuous.

Comment: You can substitute x1 and x2 and turn this into a simple two variable problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using all the Basic Feasible solutions(BFS), found in first part.
2. From theorem  [[1]](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~cmcd/lp/lp.pdf) , every BFS <=> extreme point of feasible set
3. From theorem [[1]](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~cmcd/lp/lp.pdf), If an LPP has an optimal solution then it has an optimal solution at an extreme point of the feasible set.